# Bookmarklet/javascript to post to message board?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm looking for a way to post to a message board via a bookmarklet, to make the process easier when doing so from a smartphone. Is this even possible?

This would be a message board that I am already a logged in member of. This would be for an ongoing thread where I am posting status updates and do not need to actually visit the page when posting.

The end goal would be to use this with the Drafts app for iPhone, so I can quickly type out an update and then post it to the specific thread.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way: Inspect the code of the form on the message board that is used to sumbit a post. Find the form action and the form variables. Bookmarklet can then submit form variables directly to the form action.

If simple way is blocked by some barriers or complications, can try a two step process like below.

1.) Run bookmarklet on page with data and it navigates to the message board (possibly in a new tab) but appends the data to the URL hash first. Like `http://someforumsite.tld/topic1#title=abc&body=xyz`

2.) Run bookmarklet again on the forum site to read data from hash, enter it into the form on the page, and submit the form.